# How to run Prefect over https with nginx?

Tags: security, ssl, networking, https, prefect

I have a server running CentOS 7. On this server Prefect is installed and runs over port 4200. I access Prefect over http://localhost:4200/xyz. I would like to run Prefect over https. So the goal is to be able to call https://localhost/4200/xyz and access the Prefect UI.
One possible approach is to install nginx on the server and create a self signed certificate.

So here is what I did:

1. yum install nginx
2. systemctl start nginx
3. systemctl enable nginx
4. nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/prefect.conf

**prefect.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost-ip;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost-ip;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/nginx.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost-ip:4200;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
}
```

5. systemctl restart nginx
6. Now when I enter http://localhost there is warning if I rly trust the website. I say yes and now I´m on https://localhost. It usually should open Prefect UI but I have a 502 "Bad Gateway nginx/1.20.1"-Error

Does anyone have any idea how I can pass the 502 error and achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

That setup is working for me. I only get a 502 if I don't have the prefect server running. Make sure you're starting the server like this:

```
prefect server start --host 0.0.0.0
```

Btw, you'll also need to modify your prefect config values for

```
PREFECT_API_TLS_INSECURE_SKIP_VERIFY
PREFECT_API_URL
PREFECT_UI_API_URL
PREFECT_UI_URL
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of how to configure each of those four variables? I'm checking the docs, and the differences are not obvious. `PREFECT_API_URL` and `PREFECT_UI_API_URL`, and `PREFECT_UI_URL` are different how?